# react-native PanResponder not behaving as expected on web

Tags: react-native, panresponder

Please take a look at this example on the react native docs.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder

On a device, if you start a touch outside of the box and then drag over the box, the PanResponder doesn't trigger (this is the expected behaviour)

But on web, if you start a click outside of the box then drag your mouse over the box, the box will start dragging along with your cursor.

Is there a way to only trigger the PanResponder if the click started on the element that is responding?

[image]

Comment: just added to expo issues https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/26598

Comment: seems to be working at https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/github/necolas/react-native-web/tree/master/packages/react-native-web-examples?file=%2Fpages%2Fpan-responder%2Findex.js%3A91%2C50 don't have time to look into it any further at the mo'.